# Juntar dois eventos que tem a mesma função

Tags: javascript, html, html5, eventos, html-tags

Eu sou novo em programação e eu estava criando um código html, em que eu estou chamando funções JS no meu próprio input.

Enfim, eu tenho esse trecho, no meu código do input:

```
<input type="text" onclick="setTimeout(funcaojs, 1)" onkeydown="setTimeout(funcaojs, 1)">
```

Repare que eu repito uma parte do código duas vezes. Como estou em busca de aprendizado e aprimoração do meu código, resolvi recorrer a vcs.

Tem alguma maneira de eu juntar os dois eventos para nao repetir o código? algo como:

```
<input type="text" (onclick, onkeydown)="setTimeout(funcaojs, 1)">
```

Sei que este exemplo meu é besta e nao funcionaria desta maneira, mas só gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de fazer isso, e se sim, como.

Agradeço a todos que puderem contribuir.

Comment: Creio eu, que isso não seja possível se quiser chamar a mesma função, mas agrupando dois evento, tera que criar um evento do mesmo jeito para o elemento e colocar a função que deseja chamar.

Comment: @LeandroNascimento, pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: O primeiro código que você escreveu em cima é o que estou me se referindo. Não é possível isso que você deseja!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é possível fazer o que você deseja. A sintaxe de exemplo que você demonstrou na pergunta é inválida.

O que você pode fazer é criar uma função que encapsulará todo o bloco de código que você precisa executar. Após isso basta reutilizar a função em diversos *lugares*.

Algo assim:

```js
function eventHandler(message) {
  console.log('Hello! From ' + message)
}
```

```html
<input onclick="eventHandler('Focou')" onblur="eventHandler('Desfocou')" />
```

Tente focar e desfocar o *input*. Você agora está utilizando a mesma função para dois eventos distintos.

---

PS: A medida que o seu código cresce, passa ser ruim definir os eventos diretamente no HTML. APIs como o [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) são recomendadas, já que com elas você pode definir o evento diretamente no código JavaScript.

E é importante salientar que o `addEventListener` **não aceita múltiplos eventos** ao mesmo tempo. Você precisa criar o *listener* individualmente para cada evento.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('button');

function handler(type) {
  console.log('Evento! ->', type);
}

el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => handler('Entrou'));
el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => handler('Saiu'));
```

```html
<button>Passe o Mouse!</button>
```

Comment: E com o `addEventListener` eu consigo algo como `id.addEventListener('click change mouseup', funcaojs())`?

Comment: Não. Editei a pergunta adicionando mais detalhes.

Answer (score 4):

Pode fazer assim:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" onclick="funcao()" onkeydown="this.click()">
```

JS:

```
const funcao = _ => alert(1);
```

Mas eu faria assim:

```js
const funcao = _ => alert(1),
input = document.querySelector('input[name="meuinput"]');

['click', 'keydown'].forEach(i => input.addEventListener(i, funcao));
```

```html
<input name="meuinput" type="text" /">
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas acho que isso não ajuda muito, estou buscando uma maneira de diminuir minha tag, trazendo menos código.

Answer (score 4):

O que vc pode fazer e levar a função para fora da tag e fazer um script associando o elemento que vai ter a interação, assim vc pode atribuir vários `eventListners` ao mesmo elemento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo eu adiciona vários listeners ao mesmo btn, não é um exemplo usual, mas da para vc entender como ter várias interações com o elemento utilizando a mesma função.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
function minhaFunk(){
    document.body.classList.toggle('ativo');
}
btn.addEventListener('mouseover', minhaFunk);
btn.addEventListener('mouseleave', minhaFunk);
btn.addEventListener('click', minhaFunk);
```

```css
.ativo {background:red}
```

```html
<button id="btn">clicar</button>
```

Comment: Não é possível `btn.addEventListener('mouseover mouseleave click', minhaFunk);`, como é possível `$(id).on('mouseover mouseleave click', minhaFunk())` no jQuery não?

Comment: @edro jQuery é útil justamente nessas horas quando vc quer economizar algumas linhas de código, mas por debaixo dos panos é bem provável que ele esteja criando um listener para cada tipo de interação. O ES6 já absorveu muito do jQuery, mas isso até onde sei não é possível fazer de forma simples, mas aqui tem algumas anternativas pra vc estudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845678/adding-multiple-event-listeners-to-one-element

Answer (score 3):

Eu sei que a pergunta não tem a tag Jquery, mas eu vou responder na mesma pois acho que é informação util. Através de Jquery você consegue registar múltiplos eventos para o mesmo código com a função [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/). Esta função recebe como primeiro parâmetro uma `string` com os eventos a serem capturados, separados por espaço.

Veja um exemplo capturando o evento `click` e `keydown` na caixa de texto:

```js
$("#texto").on("click keydown", function(){
  console.log("evento lançado");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="texto">
```

Comment: Apesar de não ser Vanilla achei legal, não sabia dessa ;)

Answer (score 2):

Com a sintaxe do HTML não é possível, pois é estática. Você até consegue criar um pré-processador que faça o que deseja, o que facilitaria a manutenção, mas no código final acabaria sendo a mesma coisa.

### Com JavaScript, usando atributos `data`

Sem quebrar a sintaxe do HTML, com auxílio do JavaScript você conseguiria fazer algo como:

```
<input type="text" data-events="(click, keydown)=funcaojs" />
```

O código para analisar isso poderia ser bastante simples ou bem mais elaborado, dependendo das suas necessidades. Nesse caso, poderia ser algo como:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-events]')
const pattern = /^\((.*)\)=(.*)$/

for (let element of elements) {
  let config = element.dataset.events
  let groups = config.match(pattern)
  
  if (groups) {
    let events = groups[1].split(',').map(event => event.trim())
    let handler = groups[2]
    
    for (let event of events) {
      console.log(`Adicionando a função ${handler} ao evento ${event}`)
      element.addEventListener(event, window[handler])
    }
  }
}

// Função que tratará os eventos
function funcaojs(event) {
  console.log(`Evento ${event.type} disparado em um ${event.target.tagName}`)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" data-events="(click, keydown)=funcaojs" />
```

É um exemplo bastante simples e talvez não seja completamente funcional para colocar em produção, até porque meu intuito foi apenas fazer a prova de conceito da solução. Você pode (e deve) adaptá-la conforme suas necessidades.

Mas é importante ressaltar que embora seja um código simples ele se adapta à quantidade de elementos que você possui na página. Isto é, você pode utilizar o mesmo atributo `data-events` em qualquer elemento que desejar:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-events]')
const pattern = /^\((.*)\)=(.*)$/

for (let element of elements) {
  let config = element.dataset.events
  let groups = config.match(pattern)
  
  if (groups) {
    let events = groups[1].split(',').map(event => event.trim())
    let handler = groups[2]
    
    for (let event of events) {
      console.log(`Adicionando a função ${handler} ao evento ${event}`)
      element.addEventListener(event, window[handler])
    }
  }
}

// Função que tratará os eventos
function funcaojs(event) {
  console.log(`Evento ${event.type} disparado em um ${event.target.tagName}`)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" data-events="(click, keydown)=funcaojs" />
<button data-events="(click)=funcaojs">Pressione-me</button>

<h1 data-events="(mouseenter, mouseleave)=funcaojs">Passe o mouse</h1>
```

> **Nota:** utilizei em todos os eventos a função `funcaojs` para simplificar o código e por ela já exibir a mensagem de log no console, mas pode alterar e definir a função que desejar.

### Com JavaScript, utilizando o `prototype`

Como mostrado nas outras respostas, é possível adicionar uma função a um evento através do `addEventListener`, mas o mesmo não aceita mais de um evento, precisando assim chamar a função para cada evento que deseja tratar. Ou você pode se beneficiar do `prototype` do JavaScript, pois com ele você pode definir novos métodos aos seus elementos sem interferir, necessariamente, no comportamento natural do mesmo.

Assim, podemos criar a função `addEventsListener` (perceba `Events` no plural) de forma que aceite uma lista de eventos para uma mesma função, fazendo basicamente o que precisa:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.addEventsListener = function (events, listener) {
  for (let event of events) {
    this.addEventListener(event, listener)
  }
}
```

E, com isso, podemos chamar o método `addEventsListener` em qualquer elemento HTML que desejarmos passando a lista de eventos:

```
input.addEventsListener(['click', 'keydown'], funcaojs)
```

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```js
// Define a função no prototype
HTMLElement.prototype.addEventsListener = function (events, listener) {
  for (let event of events) {
    this.addEventListener(event, listener)
  }
}

// Define a função que tratará os eventos
function funcaojs(event) {
  console.log(`Evento ${event.type} disparado em um ${event.target.tagName}`)
}

// Atribui a função aos eventos
const input = document.querySelector('input')

input.addEventsListener(['click', 'keydown'], funcaojs)
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

> **Nota:** a função nativa `addEventListener` aceita mais que dois parâmetros, então seria interessante que a função definida `addEventsListener` tratasse os mesmos parâmetros para manter todo tipo de compatibilidade entre as chamadas. Para simplificar, só implementei os dois primeiros, que são o evento e a função que trata o mesmo.